# SCP Changing text file contents

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to copy a file from machine A:

```
apt policy openssh-client
openssh-client:
  Installiert:           1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4
```

to machine B:

```
apt-cache policy openssh-client
openssh-client:
    Installiert: 1:5.5p1-6+squeeze5
```

On A:

```
scp myfile <server>:/myfile
md5sum myfile
2ba67c5e816350d4d2e2e7fd883037e7
file myfile
myfile: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

On B:

```
md5sum myfile
8883620c2a0878da1db273101b55124d
file myfile
myfile: ASCII Java program text
```

Looking into the text file, it seems that every line has one more space in it than the last one, so instead of:

```
import argparse, os, sys

from subprocess import check_output

def count_voicemails(dir):
    # find is faster than ls, since it does not check attributes
    command = 'find {}/INBOX -maxdepth 1 | wc -l'
    count   = int(check_output(command.split()))
    return count
```

It looks like this:

```
import argparse, os, sys

from subprocess import check_output

 def count_voicemails(dir):
       # find is faster than ls, since it does not check attributes
           command = 'find {}/INBOX -maxdepth 1 | wc -l'
               count   = int(check_output(command.split()))
                   return count
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same file? In your scp command, you're sending the file to /myfile. If you're looking at a file with the same name in your home directory, that would explain the issue. (Especially if you've already tried to copy the file into a vim edit window customized to repeat spaces at the beginning of lines.)

Comment: @JennyD: Beat me to it and I am 95% sure that you could write this as an answer outright :)

Comment: @JennyD goddamit, I pasted it into vim originally and then scp actually did not overwrite the destination file.

Comment: @mzhaase: I've never experienced this with `vim`, but in `joe` I get this problem with the evermore indentation when pasting into an SSH session all the time.

Comment: Not that I personally have ever experienced this, or a version thereof *cough*

Comment: And especially not spent several minutes trying to figure it out. No, sirree.

Comment: To avoid this indentation when pasting in vim, use `set paste`.

Comment: if an SCP is modifying your files, i would suggest contacting the Foundation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your scp command sends the file to the root of the target server - you're scp:ing to `/myfile`. When you later look at the file, you're not giving the full path. It looks as though you have once tried to copy the contents of a file using an editor configured to insert indentation from the previous line, and that's the file you're looking at.